# Bootstrap Look and feel in 4.0 Milestone 19 overrides my styles

Tags: orbeon

Loaded Milestone 20 of 4.0 and all my screen layouts and dialogs are trashed.
I use an inline style for the input fields as all my input fields are different sizing,  and I see that the Bootstrap look and feel sets a standard size of 206px. It appears to ignore my style.

```
<xf:secret id="loginUsername" appearance="minimal" xxf:size="8" ref="instance('login')/username" style="width: 80px; verticalAlign: middle;"><xf:label/><xf:hint>User Name</xf:hint></xf:secret><br/>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: CSS rules work based on priorities, so one thing to do is to use Firebug in Firefox or the Chrome dev tools to see which CSS rule(s) in Bootstrap or Orbeon overrides which of your CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap sets a width on `input` elements, so the `width: 80px` you set there with your style on the containing `span` has no effect. I think the best way is to use a `class` on the `xf:secret`, and other control, instead of a `style`, and then use an external CSS to set the width of the `input` based on that class, with a rule which is stronger than what Bootstrap has.

Since your form is using Bootstrap, I imagine that you created it with Form Builder, in which case see the section [Writing your own CSS](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Writing-your-own-CSS).

Comment: Thanks, the use of a class seems to be work better. There are some situations where this does not work - (e.g. autocomplete - you can set the width of the main input, but it does not affect the drop-down) - Am looking at the css classes to try and override this.